# How Magento2 stores the Full page cache?

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

I'm trying to find out how Magento 2 handles the storage of the response. I know that it stores the raw data in /var/page_cache/ folder, but I would like to know which part of the code handles the storage of a page?

I looked every file in the PageCache module with no luck. Could you point me into the right direction?

Page cache module:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/code/Magento/PageCache

Comment: Do you use Varnish or php page cache?

Comment: @KAndy php page cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PageCache module use `Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Cache` class to work with cache. It's class extends `Magento\Framework\App\Cache` that is proxy of proxy for Zend_Cache_Core class

Comment: Thank, looks I found some explanation here: http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/134802803800/magento-2-full-page-caching-code-points

Comment: Thanks, I accept yours as solution, but if someone has to go deeper: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111118/how-magento2-stores-the-full-page-cache

Answer (score 0):

Try search in vendor\magento\framework\Cache\Core.php  and vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Cache\

Comment: Could you point the file in the repository which gets the whole response and tell the framework to cache it? I want to know where the full page cache gets the response and start the caching procedure. (I do not want to know how it goes into a cache file.)

Comment: Magento\Framework\Cache\Core::save use parent method save (Zend_Cache_Core::save)